# Upload to S3 constantly fails with SignatureDoesNotMatch error

Tags: post, upload, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

I'm following this guide: http://aws.amazon.com/articles/1434/ and I'm clearly missing something, because I keep getting SignatureDoesNotMatch error every time I try to upload something.
This is my policy:

```
{"expiration": "2099-01-01T00:00:00Z",
    "conditions": [ 
    {"bucket": "<my bucket>"}, 
    {"key": "${filename}"},
    {"acl": "private"}
    ]
}
```

I guest this is the only kind of information I can give at the moment. This is the html page: http://pastebin.com/9dNSsgqZ

Any ideas?

EDIT:
The problem was in the way I was creating the signature. Here`s a link in case someone ( like me ) wants a working solution: http:// aws.amazon.com/code/Amazon-S3/1618

Comment: I'm guessing the problem is in the `<signed with the secret key and then base64-encoded>` step. How are you calculating the signature?

Comment: Exactly as described in the guide.

_Calculate a signature value (SHA-1 HMAC) from the encoded policy document using your AWS Secret Key credential as a password. Include this value in the form’s signature input field after Base64-encoding it._